# Installing Unity on 10.04 for netbooks

Tags: unity, 10.04, apt, ubuntu-netbook

I have installed Ubuntu 10.04 LTS netbook version and it comes with an annoying user interface. I'd like to know how I can replace it with Unity. I've already tried `sudo apt-get install unity` but it comes up with an error saying that the package named unity can't be found. Looking on Google I couldn't find any more help on the subject.

(before you ask me why I haven't installed 11.04, that's because it would not start up from the live CD at all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity is not available for 10.04 LTS.

However, the LTS is only for desktops - as per the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS)

> In 10.04, the Netbook Edition was not an LTS.

It is recommended that you download 11.04 again, run a checksum to make sure the file is OK, and then try again - be patient, the 11.04 LiveCD takes a long time (about 4-5 minutes for me) to boot up.

Comment: Ok. I'll try tomorrow and keep you updated.

Comment: Did you try again? Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Here a video about install Unity Netbook edition, feel free to try before to install 11.04

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ekCFCJsMmZM

Comment: This would be more appropriate as a comment instead of an answer, so please use comments next time.